# How to totally refresh a sqlite database in object-c project?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm using FMDB in my project, I constructed the first sqlite3 database in terminal, and loaded it into my project. Later I made some changes to that database, so I deleted it from project (move to trash), and "add files" again. But the running result seems still accord to the previous database or sometimes just no query result. I also tried to remove the database and run project, it's still running with no error... Additionally, I imported a newer database with another name, it can't work either. So is there anything additional I need to do to totally remove a database in objective-c and reload one? Thanks!

My code shows as below:

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {        
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"finalCarpool.db"];
    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];

    NSLog(@"Is SQLite compiled with it's thread safe options turned on? %@!", [FMDatabase isSQLiteThreadSafe] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
    }
    FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select * from userinfo"];
    int count=0;
    while ([rs next]) {
        count++;
        NSLog(@"%i",count);

    }
    FMResultSet *rs2 = [db executeQuery:@"select id from userinfo where username = ? AND password= ?", usernameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
    if ([rs2 next]) {

        NSString *welcomeMessage=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Welcome, %@",usernameTextField.text];
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Successfully Login!"
                                message:welcomeMessage
                                delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];

        [self.loginDelegate backToLaunch];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Something is wrong..."
                                message:@"Your username and/or password doesn't match!Please try again!"
                                delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
        usernameTextField.text=Nil;
        passwordTextField.text=Nil;
    }
[usernameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on the simulator, the database path is

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<SIMULATOR-VERSION>/Applications/<APP-NAME>/Documents/finalCarpool.db
```

You can delete it from there.
Otherwise you can just delete the application from the simulator (in the same way you would do from the iPhone).

Comment: Yeah, I found it and deleted the application both from simulator and the directory path. But the project runs still with no result (no output the resultset), while I'm sure the database has data. I have two questions that: 1) to reload a database, should I only need to delete the previous application in the simulator also delete and add new database through project navigator? 2) I'm using the [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), can I just delete the fmdb.m and use the class resources shown as above? Or I need to do some modifications to query and update?

Answer (score 0):

Go TO Ios Simulator> ResetContent and setting